# mysql if while and else causing troubles

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I need to display the last invoice number from 3 different categories of invoices types, if there is a invoice already the system just add +1 to the invoice number or if there is the first invoice it just add 0000000001 as the first invoice number.

```
    <option value="boleta" data-price="
<?php $boletas=mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT * FROM ventas 
WHERE documento = 'boleta' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($boleta=mysqli_fetch_assoc($boletas)) 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($boletas) > 0) { echo
        str_pad($boleta['folio']+1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
 else {
    echo "000000000000001";
}?>">boleta</option>
    <option value="factura" data-price="
<?php $facturas=mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE documento = 'factura' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($factura=mysqli_fetch_assoc($facturas)) 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($facturas) > 0) { echo
        str_pad($factura['folio']+1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
 else {
    echo "000000000000001";
}?>">boleta</option>
    <option value="nota" data-price="
<?php $notas=mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE documento = 'nota' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($nota=mysqli_fetch_assoc($notas)) 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($notas) > 0) { echo
        str_pad($nota['folio']+1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
 else {
    echo "000000000000001";
}?>">boleta</option>
```

When I run only 1 query it works and display the data correct but when I try to query the 3 queries it just dont display any data but only in the first `<option>`

EDIT

The ELSE is not working

Comment: i would strongly urge you not to code like this, hard to read, maintain,debug

Comment: Enable error-reporting and check your logs, that will tell you a lot where to look. And follow smiths advice, format your code better and make it easier to read. That in turn makes it easier to debug. And I would also recommend you look into using a single query instead of 3. And finally, your else is still inside the `while` loop, so if there are no rows, that codeblock will never be executed,

Comment: any sugestion example Qirel please ?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I mean how to run it all in one query or how in example to do it the right way ?

Comment: you've been given an answer below; have you not seen that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$boletas=mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT * FROM ventas 
WHERE documento = 'boleta' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($boleta=mysqli_fetch_assoc($boletas)) 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($boletas) > 0) { echo
        str_pad($boleta['folio']+1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
 else {
    echo "000000000000001";
}
```

To:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE documento = 'boleta' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($boletas = mysqli_query($datacenter, $sql)) {
    if ($boleta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($boletas)) {
        echo str_pad($boleta['folio']+1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    else {
        echo "000000000000001";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Query failed for boletas!";
}
```

This is a lot more readable, includes some error checking, and will display the required invoice number `000000000000001` if there are no results.

As an aside, I don't think using a single query is really practical for your question because of the nature of the different queries you are using. It would end up requiring 3 subqueries anyway.

Comment: Hi Nicalanica, did this help?